# Badges in Staging Area of Area51 vs Discussion Zone

Tags: support, badges, area-51

When I look at my badge-count at the top of each page in Area51, I have 3 badges in the Discussion Zone but 4 badges in the Staging Area.  Is there a reason for this discrepency or is this a bug?

**EDIT**

Per my comment to Matthew Read's answer, I am changing this to no longer have "bug" in the title and posting a [new discussion question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101776/modal-issue-between-area51-staging-area-and-discussion-zone) about modal issues of Discussion vs Staging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Staging / Discuss is basically the same as Main / Meta on regular SE sites.  Badges are separate: Meta badges are determined by your participation on Meta, not the main site.

Comment: So then it seems like an issue of poor modal representation. Meta and Main are distinctly separate sites, and obviously so - you can only get to Meta by clicking the Meta link on the page. Whereas Discussion **Zone** and Staging **Area** suggest two sections of one site, look identical and you can go between the two accidentally and without realizing it.